# What church was before St. Nicholas Church, Solohead and Oola, Ireland?

Tags: ireland, church-records, catholic-church

I'm looking for which church my family would have used in "Solohead and Oola".
St. Nicholas (Solohead and Oola) Church was built in 1887. Did it replace another St. Nicholas Church? Or was there another church in the area?

Here is a video of the current church:
https://youtu.be/-DY2h8pE4Rk?t=24m

Comment: There was an earlier church or chapel on the site: http://www.irelandgenweb.com/irltip/Records/SoloheadGraveyard.htm has burials going back to the 1740s at least. and there are baptism records going back to 1809 https://registers.nli.ie/parishes/0278